# Magento2 - Value of rewritten ListProduct::getProductDetailsHtml Method do not print out value

Tags: magento2, overrides, product-list

Magento 2.1 CE

Hi,

i do something like this:

Create a new Module with di rewrite, etc ...

Than rewrite the ListProduct Block from Mage Core:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct as MagentoListProduct;

class ListProduct extends MagentoListProduct
{
    public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
    {
        $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('SomeVendor\SomeModule\Block\Catalog\DoSomething')
            ->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('SomeVendor_SomeModule::catalog/product/list/dosomething.phtml')->toHtml();

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Where getProductDetailsHtml is the orig. Magento Block Method call in the product list template:

```
...
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
<?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
...
```

My Problem ist, that public function getProductDetailsHtml() do not return a value. The Template do not render any content out!

If i place a var_dump, like this:

```
public function getProductDetailsHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('SomeVendor\SomeModule\Block\Catalog\DoSomething')
        ->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('SomeVendor_SomeModule::catalog/product/list/dosomething.phtml')->toHtml();

    var_dump($html);
    return $html;
}
```

it dumps out the value!

If i add a new Method in my rewritten block, like:

```
public function getProductDetailsHtmlFoo(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product)
{
    $html = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Come\ProductListSwatches\Block\Catalog\Swatches')
        ->setProduct($product)->setTemplate('Come_ProductListSwatches::catalog/product/list/swatches.phtml')->toHtml();

    return $html;
}
```

and in Frontend:

```
<?php echo $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, $templateType); ?>
<?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtml($_product); ?>
<?php echo $block->getProductDetailsHtmlFoo($_product); ?>
```

it will work as i want!

Do is miss something? Whats wrong?

Comment: Hi @andre bubner, i have same issue 
Are you get solution ?

Comment: Have u same issue. any body have solution